# Blazor WASM Brotli compression via Nginx not working

Tags: nginx, blazor, blazor-webassembly, plesk, brotli

I am trying to compress my Blazor application as much as possible by following [their compression section](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0#compression). When I run `dotnet publish -c Release` it will automatically create both `.gz` and `.br` files. I run the site through Nginx on a Plesk server, and I have confirmed Brotli compression works simply by testing my site via https://www.brotli.pro/

When I load the site, files like blazor.wasm (~1000 KB) are loaded with these response headers:

```
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/wasm
Content-Length: 1010659
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

However, other static files like JSON and CSS files are loaded with `Content-Encoding: br`. The DLLs and files from Blazor aren't even loaded with GZip compression as a fallback, even though the request headers say they can:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

I can get around this by following Microsoft's guide, and adding `decode.min.js` from [Google's Brotli library](https://github.com/google/brotli/), however, that adds ~70 KB of additional unnecessary data and honestly shouldn't be needed. If I run IIS with a web.config file it probably also works. If I visit `/blazor.wasm.br`, it starts downloading the file, so it definitely exists, which was also confirmed by using the Brotli decoder script.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a combination of updating to HTTP/2 on my Plesk server and adding `brotli_static on;` under additional nginx directives worked.